# How can I parse a part of the GET request in Django's function-based view

Tags: django, parsing, url, request, get

I am passing to Django's function-based view this URL:

`<hostname>/display_listing/1`

The number 1 in the above URL is an ID field in a database. I would like my function-based view that is triggered with the above URL to parse the ID from the URL (number 1 in this case) so I can use it later to get an entry from the database.

My question is how I can parse this ID from the URL?

My function_based view currently looks like this:

```
def display_listing(request):
  print(f"request: {request}\n")
  ... <more code to come here>...
  return render(request, 'auctions/test.html', {"id": "id"})
```

Output:

`request: <WSGIRequest: GET '/display_listing/1'>`

The above output tells me that that the view did receive the right ID (number 1), now I need to somehow put it into a variable. I am new to Django, will appreciate any hint.

I googled for a solution, did not find it so far.

Comment: share the `urls.py`.

Answer (score 0):

In the path, you specify that it should capture a sequence of digits and put it in a parameter named `pk` with:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('display_listing/<int:pk>/', display_listing),
]
```

and in the view you add an `pk` parameter:

```
def display_listing(request, pk):
    # …
    return render(request, 'auctions/test.html', {'id': pk})
```

---

> **Note**: Please do *not* name a variable `id`, it overrides the reference to the [**`id`** builtin function <sup>[Python-doc]</sup>](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id). Use for example `pk`.